# Implementing a recursive lambda function in Java

Tags: java, recursion, lambda

I don't know if the following thing is possible.  I would like a `Runnable`'s `run()` method to contain the `Runnable` itself, i.e.

```
reconnects = 3;
Runnable executeAfter = () -> {
    if ( --reconnects < 0 ) {
        println("%nStop using port %d.", this.port);
        //...
    } else { // try to reconnect
        println("%nReconnecting...");
        cmdRun = new CmdRun(command, executeAfter);
        (new Thread(cmdRun)).start();
        //...
    }
};
```

Is something like this even possible?  If so, how?  (`CmdRun`'s constructor is `CmdRun(String command, Runnable executeAfter)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is lambda a must here? If not, switching to older equivalent syntax should be simple:

An example:

```
public class TestLambda {
    static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // lambda not going to work
        //Runnable foo = () -> { if (count < 5) { call(foo); } };
        // nor
        //Runnable foo = () -> { if (count < 5) { call(this); } };

        // using old way of anonymous inner class will work
        Runnable foo = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                if (count < 5) {
                    call(this);
                }
            }
        };

        foo.run();
    }

    public static void call(Runnable action) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("in call " + count);
        action.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: although it works, but doing something like retry/reconnect etc recursively, and spawning new thread in each level of recursion seems to be error prone.  Consider changing the design

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to put the content of your lambda in a method and use a method reference to define your Runnable.

Answer (score 1):

The Runnable's run() can not contain a self reference as its illegal.
Im not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but something like this should work :

```
class CmdRun implements Runnable {

    final Object command;
    final Runnable runnable;

    final Runnable executeAfter = () -> {
        if ( --reconnects < 0 ) {
            System.out.println("%nStop using port %d." + port);
            //...
        } else { // try to reconnect
            System.out.println("%nReconnecting...");
            CmdRun cmdRun = new CmdRun(command);
            (new Thread(cmdRun)).start();
            //...
        }
    };

    public CmdRun(Object command) {
        this.command = command;
        this.runnable = executeAfter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:**
Your code will give you a syntax error. Why? The `executeAfter` used inside the lambda is not initialized; it is only initialized after the full body of the lambda definition.

For example, consider the below example.

```
int i;
sum(i, 5); // Syntax error!! Variable i is not initialized...
```

Your case is similar. Inside the lambda, `executeAfter` is not initialized. As stated above, it is only initialized after the full body of the lambda's definition.

One additional thing to node is that the variable `reconnects` must be a final in order to be used inside the lambda. If it is a final variable, then you cannot use the `--` operator on it inside your if condition.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you don't mind to introduce a new interface (or if you require such functionality more often), you could use the following:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface RecursiveRunnable extends Runnable {
    default void run() {
        run(this);
    }
    public void run(RecursiveRunnable runnable);
}
```

This will now allow you to recursively call the runnable, e.g.:

```
int maxTries = 3;
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
RecursiveRunnable foo = runnable -> {
    if (counter.getAndIncrement() < maxTries) {
        println("Reconnecting... %n");
        runnable.run(); // same as: runnable.run(runnable)
    } else {
        println("Stop using port %d%n", port);
    }
};
```